# How to create nested aside menu with named folders (hugo)?

Tags: hugo

I have a such folders/file structure:

- folder 1

  - file_1_1.md
  - file_1_2.md
- folder 2

  - _index.md
- folder 3

  - file_3_1.md
  - file_3_2.md
  - folder 3_1

    - file_3_1_1.md
    - file_3_1_2.md

And I want it to render like this menu:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    folder 1 <!-- there is no link, because don`t exist a file folder 1/_index.md -->
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/folder 1/file_1_1.md">file_1_1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/folder 1/file_1_2.md">file_1_2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/folder 2">folder 2</a> <!-- there is a link, because exist a file folder 2/_index.md -->
  </li>
  <li>
    folder 3 <!-- there is no link, because don`t exist a file folder 3/_index.md -->
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="/folder 3/file_3_1.md">file_3_1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/folder 3/file_3_2.md">file_3_2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        folder 3_1 <!-- there is no link, because don`t exist a file folder 3/folder 3_1/_index.md -->
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/folder 3/folder 3_1/file_3_1_1.md">file_3_1_1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/folder 3/folder 3_1/file_3_1_2.md">file_3_1_2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Can I do it automatically? So that when a new folder and file is added, the menu changes. (something like `sectionPagesMenu = "main"`)
2. If it is not possible automatically, how to do it to indicate where in the menu there will be links, and where is just text indicating the folder?

Comment: Did you check out https://hugocodex.org/add-ons/nested-menu/?